# Spring Cloud Dataflow - Setting Stream Apps Env Variables

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm deploying a Spring Cloud Dataflow stream onto Cloud Foundry.  I need to set an environment variable for the underlying stream applications.  I know that putting in configuration into the stream definition will update the SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON env variable, but I want to create a new env variable.

There is a reference I see to use the following configuration:

```
spring.cloud.deployer.local.envVarsToInherit
```

To get this to work, I've tried putting the following environment variables in my Spring Cloud Dataflow Server:

```
ABCD = VALUE
spring.cloud.deployer.local.envVarsToInherit = ABCD
```

However, when I deploy the stream, the underlying stream applications don't appear to be inheriting ABCD.  Is there something I am missing to get an environment variable set on an underlying application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The property `spring.cloud.deployer.local.envVarsToInherit` is applicable only to `local` deployer and not for CF deployer. To set any environment variables for the `stream` application running inside the data flow server, it is recommended you provide the app/deployer properties via Stream DSL as documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-dataflow-create-stream.html#_application_properties)

Comment: Also, as you stated, by default deployment properties are passed as json via the `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` environment variable (this is to avoid issues with env vars escape limitations. If you want your properties to be sent as individual, actual, ENV VARS, please set `SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_USE_SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` to `false`